# C (C89) when assigning a struct to a struct variable using a for loop they all get set to the value of the first iteration result

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

I have a function which returns a location structure, which is they assigned to a ship. The problem i have is that when i loop through the ships using a for loop, the returned location structure is the value that is set for ALL iterations of the for loop.

When i print to the terminal, the function does actually calculate the values correctly, and they so in fact have different values.

Can anybody see why the value stays as the value returned in the first iteration?

A location structure has 2 double variables loc and lat.

mday_ptr is an array of mayday calls which has a ship pointer

ship is a ship* which has a location struct as a member

code:

```
for(i=0; i < mday_size; i++){
    (mday_ptr + i)->ship->loc = calculate_new_ship_loc(
                        (mday_ptr + i)->ship->loc, (mday_ptr + i)->ship->speed,
                        (mday_ptr + i)->ship->course, time_diff);

                printf("updated latitude : %f \t new longitude: %f \n",
                        mday_ptr->ship->loc.lat, mday_ptr-> ship->loc.lng);(mday_ptr + i)->ship->loc = calculate_new_ship_loc(
                        (mday_ptr + i)->ship->loc, (mday_ptr + i)->ship->speed,
                        (mday_ptr + i)->ship->course, time_diff);

                printf("updated latitude : %f \t new longitude: %f \n",
                        mday_ptr->ship->loc.lat, mday_ptr-> ship->loc.lng);
    }
}
```

The function which return a location:

```
location calculate_new_ship_loc(location loc, float spd, float crs,
        float t_diff) {

    printf("start lat : %f \t start lng: %f\n", loc.lat, loc.lng);
    location new_loc;

    double LTF;
    double LGF;

    float course_in_rad;
    float lat_in_rad;

    course_in_rad = crs * M_PI / 180.0;
    lat_in_rad = loc.lat * M_PI / 180.0;

    LTF = (loc.lat) + (spd * cos(course_in_rad) * t_diff) / 3600;

    LGF = (loc.lng) + (spd * sin(course_in_rad) * t_diff /
            cos(lat_in_rad)) / 3600;

    new_loc.lat = LTF;
    new_loc.lng = LGF;

     printf("end lat : %f \t end lng: %f\n", new_loc.lat, new_loc.lng);

    return new_loc;

}
```

Output:

```
start lat : 51.750000    start lng: -4.300000
end lat : 51.766603      end lng: -4.297654
updated latitude : 51.766603     new longitude: -4.297654 
start lat : 52.100000    start lng: -6.000000
end lat : 52.100000      end lng: -5.293325
updated latitude : 51.766603     new longitude: -4.297654 
start lat : 52.000000    start lng: -5.900000
end lat : 52.616941      end lng: -5.723307
updated latitude : 51.766603     new longitude: -4.297654
```

Comment: In your line that prints out the updated latitude and longitude, aren't you just referencing the first value each time? (You have mday_ptr instead of (mday_ptr+i))

Comment: wow. i was being stupid!

Comment: @chrisedwards You are encouraged to post an answer.

Comment: Please don't add [solved] or other markers to your question. The way to signify that you've found a solution to your problem is to accept one of the answers. (It's fine to accept your own answer too - you might just need to wait a bit before you can do that.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty trivial, the issue was when i was printitng i was always referencing the same structure.

previous code:

```
 printf("updated latitude : %f \t new longitude: %f \n",
                        mday_ptr->ship->loc.lat, mday_ptr-> ship->loc.lng);
```

solution:

```
 printf("updated latitude : %f \t new longitude: %f \n",
                        (mday_ptr + i)->ship->loc.lat, (mday_ptr + i)-> ship->loc.lng);
```